# ros-gz integration

Tags: gazebo, ros2, ros-humble

I am trying to connect ros and gazebo garden using a bridge.
I am working on ubuntu 22.04. I have ros2 humble and gazebo garden installed. I am following the readme of this repo https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz/tree/39cdcf88e762589595222d74e41f22b1d876aef1/ros_gz_bridge

I wrote a YAML file as suggested and it looks like this:

```
 ros_topic_name: "/lidar2"
 gz_topic_name: "/lidar2"
 ros_type_name: "sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan"
 gz_type_name: "gz.msgs.LaserScan"
 direction: GZ_TO_ROS
```

then I ran used this line as suggested

```
ros2 run ros_gz_bridge parameter_bridge --ros-args -p config_file:=$WORKSPACE/ros_gz/ros_gz_bridge/test/config/full.yaml
```

However, I keep getting this error

```
[WARN] [1671207408.574261249] [ros_gz_bridge]: Failed to create a bridge for topic [/lidar2] with ROS2 type [/lidar2] to topic [sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan] with Gazebo Transport type [gz.msgs.LaserScan]
```

Any idea what's the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use roz_gz with Humble & Garden you will need to build the package from source. https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz

The Humble binaries (ros-humble-ros-gz) look for Fortress message types.

Comment: It worked! Thank you