# How to debug: [ros_gz_bridge]: Failed to create a bridge for topic

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi There,

`ros_gz_bridge` reports failure while the parameters seem to be correct:

```
$ ros2 run ros_gz_bridge parameter_bridge /cmd_vel@geometry_msgs/Twist@gz.msgs.Twist
[INFO] [1671392523.581891853] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/cmd_vel (gz.msgs.Twist) -> /cmd_vel (geometry_msgs/Twist)] (Lazy 0)
[WARN] [1671392523.582115037] [ros_gz_bridge]: Failed to create a bridge for topic [/cmd_vel] with ROS2 type [/cmd_vel] to topic [geometry_msgs/Twist] with Gazebo Transport type [gz.msgs.Twist]
```

I'm using Gazebo **Garden** on the `osrf/ros:humble-desktop` Docker image. I have a robot in the simulation that i can control with the Teleop widget on the `/cmd_vel` topic. I installed the `ros-humble-ros-gz-bridge` with apt.

What else should i check to find the cause of the issue?

**Update**
Using `ignition.msgs.Twist` instead of `gz.msgs.Twist` removes the error, (even though i'm using Gazebo Garden). But the messages are still not transferred.

It seems like Gazebo is using the `gz.` version of the message. This could explain why ROS2 messages have no effect on the simulation:

```
gz topic -i -t  /cmd_vel 
Publishers [Address, Message Type]:
  tcp://172.17.0.1:39535, ignition.msgs.Twist
  tcp://172.17.0.1:42165, gz.msgs.Twist
```

**Maybe i don't have some ROS message definitions installed?** I installed `gz-garden` and `ros-humble-gazebo-msgs` from the official PPA.

For more info, `ros2 topic info` with the bridge, teleop_keyboard, and a `ros2 echo` running:

```
ros2 topic info -v /cmd_vel
Type: geometry_msgs/msg/Twist

Publisher count: 2

Node name: ros_gz_bridge
Node namespace: /
Topic type: geometry_msgs/msg/Twist
Endpoint type: PUBLISHER
GID: 01.0f.50.71.51.ab.45.39.01.00.00.00.00.00.12.03.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
QoS profile:
  Reliability: RELIABLE
  History (Depth): UNKNOWN
  Durability: VOLATILE
  Lifespan: Infinite
  Deadline: Infinite
  Liveliness: AUTOMATIC
  Liveliness lease duration: Infinite

Node name: teleop_twist_keyboard
Node namespace: /
Topic type: geometry_msgs/msg/Twist
Endpoint type: PUBLISHER
GID: 01.0f.50.71.da.d3.49.82.01.00.00.00.00.00.11.03.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
QoS profile:
  Reliability: RELIABLE
  History (Depth): UNKNOWN
  Durability: VOLATILE
  Lifespan: Infinite
  Deadline: Infinite
  Liveliness: AUTOMATIC
  Liveliness lease duration: Infinite

Subscription count: 2

Node name: ros_gz_bridge
Node namespace: /
Topic type: geometry_msgs/msg/Twist
Endpoint type: SUBSCRIPTION
GID: 01.0f.50.71.51.ab.45.39.01.00.00.00.00.00.13.04.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
QoS profile:
  Reliability: RELIABLE
  History (Depth): UNKNOWN
  Durability: VOLATILE
  Lifespan: Infinite
  Deadline: Infinite
  Liveliness: AUTOMATIC
  Liveliness lease duration: Infinite

Node name: _ros2cli_205184
Node namespace: /
Topic type: geometry_msgs/msg/Twist
Endpoint type: SUBSCRIPTION
GID: 01.0f.50.71.80.21.50.1f.01.00.00.00.00.00.05.04.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
QoS profile:
  Reliability: RELIABLE
  History (Depth): UNKNOWN
  Durability: VOLATILE
  Lifespan: Infinite
  Deadline: Infinite
  Liveliness: AUTOMATIC
  Liveliness lease duration: Infinite
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28662/how-to-debug:-%5Bros_gz_bridge%5D:-failed-to-create-a-bridge-for-topic/) by [azazdeaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34541/azazdeaz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 41 on 2022-12-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [azazdeaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34541/azazdeaz/) on 2022-12-19**:
For reference, a question about probably the same issue on robotics.stackexchange: [ros-gz integration](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/24197/ros-gz-integration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Did you build from source? If not, this could be the problem. The pre-built bridge is looking for Fortress types on the gz topics, and failing to find them.

https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz

---

Originally posted by [clydemcqueen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3875/clydemcqueen/) with karma: 62 on 2022-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [azazdeaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/34541/azazdeaz/) on 2022-12-20**:
Thank you!